# Qual a finalidade do comando "return true;" no final de uma função?

Tags: javascript, html

Notei que em muitas funções no javascript eu vejo no final um `return true`.

```
function EscreveDados(){
    document.getElementById("divData").value = 'texto';
    return true;
}
```

e no HTML temos a *tag* que chama a função seguida de um "return" também.

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="return EscreveDados()">
    <textarea id="divData"></textarea>
</form>
```

Qual a finalidade do uso desses `return` dentro do código? Eu tenho essa dúvida porque eu fiz o teste e tirei os `return` e aparentemente a função funcionou normalmente, qual seria a diferença entre usar ou não usar o `return`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No geral pode usar em algum lugar que espera uma função que retorne sucesso ou falha na operação, ou seja um `boolean`. Se a função for usada onde não precisa de um resultado específico não tem importância e não causa problemas.

Neste caso específico é óbvio que sempre haverá sucesso. Se não tivesse isto, por padrão seria assumido que o retorno foi `false`, ou seja, a validação falhou, e não é esta a intenção.

Neste seu caso o retorno `true` é importante para informar ao HTML que está tudo ok e o envio (`submit`) deve ser feito normalmente como é o padrão. Se retornasse `false` o navegador trataria a ação como um envio a não ser realizado, alterando o funcionamento padrão.

Na aparência não tem nada errado, mas dependendo de como lide com isto, pode não funcionar como espera.

O `return` no HTML é desnecessário.

Alias, este é um mecanismo considerado obsoleto. Seria melhor usar o [`preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault), mas este não é o foco da pergunta.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).